# How to randomize ascending list of values into two similar groups in R

Tags: r

I want to randomize ascending list of values in to two similar groups in R.

two statistical similar groups, meaning the mean timen (performance) is the same. (the lower timen the better) i would like a evenly distributed groups with fast and slow skiers

I will have a Pre-test and want to randomize some alpine ski athletes besed on there performance.

The datassett will look like this; (this is test datasett, the real one (with n =40) will i get at thePre-test)

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   BIB. [4]
   BIB.  `11`  `99`  `77` performance
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1  14.2  NA    NA        NA    
2     2  14.4  15.0  NA        -0.600
3     3  14.3  14.6  NA        -0.310
4    77  NA    12.9  61.4      NA
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: can you explain what the variables in your dataset are, and be clearer about the randomisation that you want?  I guess that you are aiming for two equally sized groups with similar levels of some pre-test variable?

Comment: I think the OP needs to define what would constitute 'similar group'

Answer (score 0):

My approach might be to sample it randomly some number of times (100?) then evaluate the means in each, and pick the smallest.
Here is how you would do that.

```
#invent some initial data
(hiris <- head(iris,n=20) |> select(perftime = Sepal.Length) |> mutate(id=row_number()))

# make 100 scrambled datasets, then evaluate them for closest mean
set.seed(42)
(nr <- nrow(hiris))
possible_sets <- map(1:100,
    ~slice_sample(.data = hiris,n = nr,replace=FALSE) |> 
      mutate(group=1*(row_number()<nr/2)))

(evaluations <- map_dbl(possible_sets,~{
 step1 <- group_by(.x,group) |> summarise(m=mean(perftime))
sqrt((step1$m[[1]]-step1$m[[2]])^2)
}))

(set_to_choose <- which.min(evaluations))

#to see the evaluation
plot(seq_along(evaluations),evaluations)
points(x=set_to_choose,
       y=evaluations[set_to_choose],
       col="red",pch=15)

#to use the 'best' set
(chosen_set <- possible_sets[set_to_choose])
```